# How to set a Function Breakpoint in thirdparty dll

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, logging, enterprise-library

I want to set a breakpoint in a get property of Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Writer.TraceSources

I try VS2010 > Debug > New Breakpoint > Break at Function:

Function:

- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Writer.TraceSources
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Writer.get_TraceSources
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Writer.get_TraceSources()

the breakpoint does not hit...any help?¿

(the background problem is that I lose TraceSources and can't log in windows event log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .NET Reflector Visual Studio Extension, downloadable from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/95789cdb-08f9-4dae-9b2f-fc45a452ad77/

Comment: Thanks!, I can Debug successfully with .NET Reflector.